# How to get/send data from a gamepad through HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, gamepad, gamepad-api

Are there any API or a tool to write and read data through an HTML page?

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't find a better source than the on here [html5rocks Gamepad API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/gamepad/).

Here is a link to the most active git project i could find [Github HTML5 Gamepad lib](https://github.com/kallaspriit/HTML5-JavaScript-Gamepad-Controller-Library)